# Android Wear and Pending Intents for Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm designing an android app that will be composed by both mobile and wear modules.
I'm planning on launching notification from the mobile module and relaying on the WearableExtender to add action that are only available in the Wear device.

My doubt relates to where the pending intents are executed, if in the wear device or in the mobile device? 
How can I launch intents that open both activities in the wear and mobile? Is this behaviour implicity or is a service required to deal with the communication?

I have dough throught the android documentation but couldn't find a definite answer to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Intent will never be sent on a different device of the one that generated it. So you have to catch it in your Wear module (with a `BroadcastReceiver`).

Then you can send a [message](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to do what you want on your other device.